# Selenium : Method is not getting executed once the browser is launched with correct url.

Tags: java, selenium, testng

My Scenario is:
Package A having 
Class X
Class Y

Class X is opening a driver and url, so have created method as opendriver() and set annotation as @BeforeTest.

In Class Y, I have created a method to clickon login link and set annotation as @Test

SO once I run the package through testng.xml, then browser is getting launched with correct url, but I am getting NullPointer Exception while executing clickon login link method.

My Question is: How do I handle above scenario? how to execute clickon login method once the url is opened

Answer (score 0):

Methond annotated with `@BeforeTest` annotation will be executed, if the corresponding class is added in you `testng.xml` in the `<test><classes><class>` tag along with the TestClass with `@Test` annotations.

Example:

```
public class TestNG1 {
    @BeforeTest
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Initialized");
    }
}

public class TestNG2 {
    @Test
    public void doSomeThing() {
        System.out.println("Test method");
    }
}
```

Then testng.xml should like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.sample.TestNG1"/>
       <class name="com.sample.TestNG2"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

So, make sure you have added the class in your `testng.xml` where you initialize the webdriver.

**Editing to give a more direct solution to the problem at hand.**

Base Class where the webdriver is initialized

```
public class BaseTest {

    private static final String HOMEPAGE = "http://www.google.com";
    private static final String HOMEPAGE_TITLE = "Google";

    protected static WebDriverWait wait;
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    }

    @Test
    public void openGoogle() {
        driver.get(HOMEPAGE);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(HOMEPAGE_TITLE));

        final String windowTitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(windowTitle);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Dependent class where the pre-initialized driver is used.

```
public class SearchTest extends BaseTest {

    private static final String SEARCH_BTN_NAME = "btnG";
    private static final String SEARCH_BOX_ID = "lst-ib";

    @Test(testName = "search", dependsOnMethods="openGoogle")
    public void search() {
        driver.findElement(By.id(SEARCH_BOX_ID)).sendKeys("Sharath Bhaskara");
        driver.findElement(By.name(SEARCH_BTN_NAME)).click();
    }

}
```

testng.xml that runs the complete test suite.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Suite" parallel="false">
  <test name="WebdriverTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.sample.project.BaseTest"/>
       <class name="com.sample.project.SearchTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Note:** The WebDriver instance in `BaseTest` is marked `protected static` as the state of the instance variable will not be saved by default.

Comment: Hi Sharat, Thanks for reply. I tried as per your suggestion but still getting NullPointerException. When I put click on Login method in Class X then it is working, but when i create object of Class X in Class Y and access the driver with an object of Class X then it is throwing the exception.

Comment: Akshay, you should probably use a `static` modifier to your driver. I have edited my answer, with the complete code to your question.